# Get all information about Facebook posts including reactions

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having a problem with the URL of the Facebook Graph API. Is there any possibility to get all the fields of a Facebook post **including reactions**? I use the following URL for the posts:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{pageName}/feed?access_token={access_token}
```

Now I'm getting data like this (which is quite nice):

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "someId",
            "from": {
                "Name": "Page name",
                "category": "Sports Team",
                "id": "someId"
            },
            "message": "Hello world!",
            [...]
            "shares": {
                "count": 1
            },
            "likes": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": "someId",
                        "name": "Some person"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        [...]
    ]
}
```

As for now I have to get the reactions (`LOVE`, `WOW`, `HAHA`, `SAD`, `ANGRY` and `THANKFUL`) by downloading the json from the following URL for **every single post** (and this is very time consuming):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{postId}?access_token={access_token}&fields=reactions
```

The only problem is that I can't get the reactions when using the "normal" URL (without `&fields`). Is there any chance to get **all** information including reactions without having to add all the fields to `&fields=from,message,likes,shares,reactions`?

Comment: _“The only problem is that I can't get the reactions when using the "normal" URL (without &fields)”_ – well then _add_ fields to your “normal URL”.

Comment: @CBroe There are like 20 fields. Do I really have to add all of these fields to the URL just to get the reactions too?

Comment: Yes, you have to. And your API call as shown should not return all those fields to begin with - at least if you are using at least API v2.4, then you would get a couple of default fields only anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From CBroe's comment:

I had to pass all the fields I wanted to save to my DB in my URL:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{pageName}/feed?access_token={access_token}&fields=id,from,message,name,[...],likes,comments,reactions,shares
```